# Is dual booting ubuntu 15.04 and windows 8.1 different from 14.04?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, 15.04

Do I need to change any steps in dual booting it? With windows 8.1 that is. (UEFI) I intend on doing it automatically rather than manually creating partitions.

Comment: Dual booting What? Two Ubuntu or Ubuntu & Windows? Be sure to have backups. There was a major bug where entire drive was erased with any auto reinstall. I believe fixed in 15.04, but better to be safe. And better to use Something Else, not difficult to just select same / (root) to reinstall into. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192

Answer (score 1):

If you have successfully dual booted Windows UEFI with Ubuntu 14.04 in the past, you can use exact same steps to dual boot Windows UEFI and Ubuntu 15.04. There is no difference here.

Answer (score -1):

From my experience, it is not too different. Just make sure to use the Disk Management on Windows to resize your Windows partition; gparted doesn't like to work well with Windows partitions.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the main problem with GParted and NTFS volumes is that a BIOS-bootable NTFS partition contains a BIOS boot loader that includes pointers, expressed as absolute sector numbers, to additional boot code. GParted won't update those pointers if you move the start of the partition, which can render it unbootable. This is *not* an issue with an EFI/UEFI-mode boot, though. That said, GParted's NTFS support is reverse-engineered and so may be less reliable than Windows' own tools; but that's hypothetical. I know of no study of the relative safety of each tool.